# Expression for placement of label 'offset from point' by azimuth field using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I need help making an expression for labelling points, such that the label is placed in one of the 8 quadrants (above point excluded), based on the azimuth field of the point.

For example, if the azimuth is from 338-23 degrees, place in quadrant 1, if the azimuth is from 24-69 degrees, place in quadrant 2, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can databind the label Placement Quadrant with this expression structure:

```
CASE 
  WHEN azimuth < 23 OR azimuth > 338 THEN 
    1 
  WHEN azimuth > 24 AND azimuth < 69 THEN
    2
  ELSE 
    3 
END
```

You may also need an expression calculating a more appropriate offset depending on the azimuth.

Update:

The offset can databind to an expression like this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN azimuth < 23 OR azimuth > 338 THEN 
    '0,-1' 
  WHEN azimuth > 24 AND azimuth < 69 THEN
    '1,0'
  ELSE 
    '-1,0' 
END
```

Negative x-values moves label west. Negative y-values moves label north. So '0,-1' means an x,y offset in 0 for x and 1 up north. Pick the unit used as map units, if you not using lat-long coordinates.

Comment: Good one. Leave it to a geologist to come up with an expression for placement of dip labels! Unfortunately you are also right about the offset. The labels are too close to the point. Any idea on an accompanying expression for offset?

Comment: Added an expression skeleton for offset.

Comment: Thanks for the skeletons Jakob. I'm posting the final expressions I used for quadrant and offset for placement of dip labels around strike/dip geology symbols.

Answer (score 1):

For quadrant:

`CASE 
  WHEN "Strike" > 325 OR "Strike" <= 25 THEN 5 
  WHEN "Strike" > 25 AND "Strike" <= 70 THEN 8 
  WHEN "Strike" > 70 AND "Strike" <= 115 THEN 7 
  WHEN "Strike" > 115 AND "Strike" <= 160 THEN 6 
  WHEN "Strike" > 160 AND "Strike" <= 205 THEN 3 
  WHEN "Strike" > 205 AND "Strike" <= 250 THEN 0 
  WHEN "Strike" > 250 AND "Strike" <= 295 THEN 1 
  WHEN "Strike" > 295 AND "Strike" <= 325 THEN 2 
 END`

For offset:

`CASE 
  WHEN "Strike" >= 0 AND "Strike" <=20 THEN '3,0' 
  WHEN "Strike" > 20 AND "Strike" <=45 THEN '2,-1' 
  WHEN "Strike" > 45 AND "Strike" <= 90 THEN '0,1' 
  WHEN "Strike" > 90 AND "Strike" <= 135 THEN '-1,1' 
  WHEN "Strike" > 135 AND "Strike" <= 180 THEN '-1.5,0' 
  WHEN "Strike" > 180 AND "Strike" <= 225 THEN '-1.5,-0.5' 
  WHEN "Strike" > 225 AND "Strike" <= 270 THEN '0,-1' 
  WHEN "Strike" > 270 AND "Strike" <= 315 THEN '0,-1' 
  WHEN "Strike" > 315 AND "Strike" <= 359 THEN '3,-0.5' 
 END`

Comment: Will there ever be a case when strike > 325 and <= 25 on the same time?? You should use OR instead of AND here.
If you happy with my answer please accept it with the accept answer button. This would close the answer and help other in the future for a status.